Can one say that the 14.1 update effectively introduced symbolic operations on infinite matrices?
Since it is possible to operate with symbolic matrices of unspecified dimensions and there are symbolic matrix constructors (SymbolicOnesArray, SymbolicIdentityArray, SymbolicDeltaProductArray), can one say that now one can operate with infinite matrices? Can one construct the matrix for the derivative operator, for instance? Or those symbolic matrix constructors are not enough?

Can you be more specific, say, show an evaluation you want to automate with Mathematica?

Yes, one can say that the Mathematica 14.1 update introduced significant advancements in symbolic operations on matrices, including infinite matrices. The update includes features for symbolic vector, matrix, and array variables. This allows for operations such as symbolic differentiation of vector, matrix, and array expressions, as well as other matrix operations like Transpose, Dot, Inverse, Det, and more.
These enhancements make it possible to perform symbolic computations on infinite matrices more effectively, expanding the capabilities of Mathematica in handling complex mathematical structures

How one can represent the matric of the derivative operator using matrix constructors?
